# Can this Eaton T0-2-8211/E changeover switch between multiple sources

Tags: switches, mains, generator

I have this Eaton 1|0|2 style changeover switch [T0-2-8211/E](https://datasheet.eaton.com/Eaton-022234-T0-2-8211-E-en_GB.pdf?model=022234&type=pdf). Can I use this to switch between 2 different *input* sources?

My intention is to use it to switch between shore and generator power on boat. It's not going to be used frequently so no automation is required. I just want to be able to switch the input source to my AC distribution panel whenever I leave the dock.

The wiring diagram that came with it looks like this [image: wiring diagram]

So I thought I could just wire Input 1 (shore power) to 1 & 3, Input 2 (generator) to 5 & 7, then have the output to the AC distribution panel be 2 & 6.

But when I tried this I had severe voltage drop whenever I applied any load. So it works fine when measured with a AC voltage meter without any current being drawn, but as soon as some load is applied the voltage drops to ~0 and get's very unstable.

What am I doing wrong, is it my wiring, or is this switch not suited for this application? I see it sometimes mentioned as a "manual motor controller" which is *not* what I'm using it for, but I figured it was just a switch.

Comment: Are you trying to draw more than 20 amps through it?

Comment: That looks like a manual reversible motor controller switch from the horrible horrible datasheet.  Note that for a power transfer switch, you need fast break before make contacts,  If you want to go looking for parts, power transfer switch is also your search term.  You're getting some sort of brownout, and if it's because the switch can't carry adequate current that's a major problem.  You definitely don't want to connect an out of phase generator to the grid, even for a moment, so be careful.

Comment: @KH no, the main fuse is 16, and even with just a few amps of load this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eaton's diagram is far from clear. I suspect that it should be connected as shown in Figure 1.

[image]

*Figure 1. Possible connection scheme.*

I'd disconnect everything and buzz out the switch at each position to confirm rather than test it with shore and generator supplies!

---

> Seems to me ... that #1 is 1 and 3 if you count from top left and down. That way the X in the "puzzle" fits with the drawing on the left, 1,3 and for #1, and 5 and 7 for #2?

[image]

*Figure 2. My reading.*

I read it as

```
         1-2     3-4     5-6     7-8
Posn1    Closed  Open    Closed  Open
Posn0    Open    Open    Open    Open
Posn2    Open    Closed  Open    Closed
```

> And I did check the voltage on each position of the switch, e.g on pos #0 no voltage, on #2 no voltage (generator not running) and on #1 ~240VAC.

Yes but the voltage collapsed when you connected a load so that sounds to me as though you're picking up stray voltage.

Bell it out for continuity.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Is there any chance of protection diodes or other circuitry in there since this thing is meant to switch motors perhaps?

Comment: No. That would be documented on the datasheet.

Comment: This must be correct, I'll confirm and upvote ASAP. Thank you @Transistor